# is it possible to make a whole blockchain from scratch using javascript?

Tags: go-ethereum, javascript, private-blockchain, nodejs

I was wondering if javascript has alot of tools of doing stuff and help with hashing and helper nodejs modules that help with web3 development but my question is it possible to make something like ethereum or solana using javascript also is it hard to do and what nodes do i need know about , do they mean a dedicated AWS servers ? can someone explain how its possible to do this with JS and is there a pros and cons of coding this using JS and GO language ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do everything in JavaScript, including Windows95 or [MacOS](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2022/04/boot-up-classic-mac-os-in-your-browser-window-with-the-infinite-mac-project/).

*(just like you can play [Doom on pregnancy test](https://twitter.com/foone/status/1302820468819288066?lang=en))*

Current list of clients: https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/nodes-and-clients/

*(there is no JavaScript client that is widely used in production)*

[image]

## https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-monorepo

> Finally, the EthereumJS Execution Client (EthereumJS) has been in active development for some time now. It already serves a variety of purposes like testing, research (e.g. EIPs) and developer tooling to engage with the protocol.

Hope that helps.

Maybe you can edit question for clarity, what exactly are you trying to achieve.

Comment: will read these , i was trying to learn how to make something similar to ethereum but in JS because its a widely used framework all over the world from creating an EVM to actually working blockchain like ethereum or bsc or solana for learning purposes

Comment: You can make a blockchain on piece of paper or in Google Doc. Hash of the previous message is appended as a header to a new file. Or this: https://learnmeabitcoin.com/ or https://www.lopp.net/bitcoin-information.html - loads of educational information available... Maybe you'll find a DIY implementation of a blockchain for learning purposes.

Comment: thank u so much Mars , these resources will be helpful to understand how node and ethereum works for building a blockchain :)